# SQL Server 2008 Timeout expired rebuild and reorganize index solve the issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, index-tuning

I have a large database with a file stream located on a different disk the server that hosts this database has a large number of another none related databases but the specifications of this server are great, my database throws a timeout exception for some queries from time to time,

every time I rebuild and reorganize the indexes the queries back to work normally, I have created a maintenance plan that do Rebuild, Reorganize and update statistics every 3 hours to avoid such issues, the fill factor for the indexes is 90%,

What are the reasons for this? and how I can avoid this issue without the maintenance plan as it adds an extra overhead on the CPU and the RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a performance issue at your hands. Investigate it appropriately, using a performance investigation methodology like [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx). [USE](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2413037) is also a great performance troubleshooting framework.

Stop [doing random changes in hope something improves](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/31/the-bizzaro-guide-to-sql-server-performance/). Measure, identify, then act appropriately. [Establish baselines](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190943.aspx). Read the entire [Monitor and Tune for Performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189081.aspx) chapter on MSDN.